# How do I fetch content from switchable tab in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There are 4 switchable tabs on the website, I managed to extract from the first tab but couldn't figure out how to extract from other three tabs because the tab needs to be clicked on (i think).

- Product Details
- Feedback
- Shipping & Payment
- Seller Guarantees

my code :

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
myurl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Vfemage-Womens-Elegant-Ruched-Bow-Contrast-Patchwork-3-4-Sleeve-Vintage-Pinup-Work-Office-Party-Fitted/32831085887.html?spm=2114.search0103.3.12.iQlXqu&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_10325_10343_51102_10546_10340_10548_10341_10609_10541_10084_10083_10307_10610_10539_10312_10313_10059_10314_10534_100031_10604_10603_10103_10605_10594_10142_10107,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=a3e03a67-d922-4c90-aba7-d3cc80101a75-1&algo_pvid=a3e03a67-d922-4c90-aba7-d3cc80101a75&rmStoreLevelAB=0'

uClient = uReq(myurl)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
productdetails = page_soup.select("ul.product-property-list.util-clearfix li")
```

How do you extract contents from the other 3 tabs ?

Comment: every tab may have own `class` or `id`. Page can also use JawaScript to load data. Use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox (tab Network -> XHR) to see JavaSrip/AJAX requests after you click tab. Maybe you find url to data as JSON

Comment: use button `{}` to format code instead of using snippet. Code will be colored and more readable.

Comment: Each tab uses javascript to grab and fill the information from the server. You will either need to recreate the calls or use something like selenium to automate a web browser to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I used Selenium to click each tabs & extract contents from all tabs with it.